# Powershell - Get AD user's initials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

All Active Directory user accounts have the property "Initials".

How do I retrieve a user's initials by using Powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have ActiveDirectory Powershell module, then you can run:

```
Get-ADUser "YourUser" -Properties Initials
```